# Twitter API increase the number of requests

Tags: api, twitter, request

I was using the Twitter API version 1.1 to retrieve a number of tweets (this number of tweets is decided by the user). Now suppose the user puts in a number which exceeds the request rate limit of Twitter API. How could I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your application needs to look for a response from Twitter that your user has hit their rate limit, and then display a message telling them so.

Attempting to find ways around the rate limit is a good way to get your app shut down by Twitter.